# Cannot retrieve windows product key using VBA - Automation Error

Tags: excel, vba, wsh

The following code throws an 'Automation Error'

```
Sub GetWindowsProductKey()

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId")

End Sub
```

But this code works fine

```
Sub GetPath()

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\Path")

End Sub
```

Clearly this has something to do with the product key being protected or something.

I'm writing a spreadsheet to collect auditing data from remote offices before anyone assumes I'm (really bad at) hacking.

---

**UPDATE**

I'm now trying the following approach, but I'm getting a type mismatch error instead on the second function (the first one still works) ...

```
Sub GetPathUsingStdRegProv()

Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = "."

Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "Environment"
strValueName = "Path"

oReg.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue

MsgBox strValue

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub GetWindowsKeyUsingStdRegProv()

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strComputer = "."

Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
strValueName = "DigitalProductId"

oReg.GetBinaryValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue

For i = LBound(strValue) To UBound(strValue)
    MsgBox strValue(i)
Next

End Sub
```

strValue is Null in the second function, which explains the type mismatch!!

---

**Update 2**

I've use the code from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32600510/5040941), along with

```
ShellRun("wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey")
```

which works on my laptop, but not on one of the desktops, presumably because the key isn't stored in BIOS/UEFI. So I'm still looking for a solution!

---

**update 3**

I've executed the code in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39530505/5040941) as a vbs script, but the value I get on my laptop is different to the one i got from `wmic` technique above?! Is that a 64-bit issue? This is all very confusing!!

Comment: try running shell as administrator...here is a link to show you how...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741940/vba-running-elevated-command-shell-vs-shellexecute?rq=1